# How can I get the database name I am connected to through Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am trying to get the name of the database I am connected to in SQL Server. I tried doing:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT db_name()");
List<String> dbNames = query.list();
```

However, I got the following error:

```
[ERROR PARSER:35] *** ERROR: <AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'db_name' {originalText=db_name}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
```

How can I get the name of the database I am connected to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either:

1. Create a native SQL query, with `session.createSQLQuery(...)`. You can extract a single row of results with `uniqueResult()`.
2. Obtain a JDBC `Connection` from the `Session`, and extract the connection string from the database meta-data. For SQL Server, I believe you'll need to parse `connection.getMetaData().getURL()` in order to extract the actual database name.

Note that `Session.connection()` is considered deprecated, and you're supposed to use `Session.doWork()`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even think about using the Connection from the Session object.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you cannot call NAtive database functions that way. Try using a Native Query instead of a simple query : http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql.shtml