# How to know underlying database name from hibernate provider

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate 3.x with Jboss.
Currently we support multiple databases.

Now in runtime, how can I know the underlying database information ? at least name or database-dialect? (e.g. MySQL, Derby, Oracle, etc)?

Can any one suggests any way to find this information?
I thought hibernate SessionFactory class will provide such api - but it is not?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821466/how-can-i-get-the-database-name-i-am-connected-to-through-hibernate

Answer (score 10):

I think you can do it this way:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().connection().getMetaData().getURL()
```

Comment: Be aware, that this method creates a abandoned connection without closing it.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks very much javamonkey79 and costis for responding to this question.

Yes - I can read the hibernate.properties/cfg.xml file - but I wanted to avoid the file reading workflow.

It appears that `Session::connection()` api is deprecated now, but it still works.
We also can retrieve the same info in another way as listed below.

## OPTION 1

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
String dbURL = session.connection().getMetaData().getURL().toString();
session.close();
```

## OPTION 2

```
Settings settings = ((SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactory).getSettings();
if (settings != null) {
    Connection connection = settings.getConnectionProvider().getConnection();
    String dbURL  = connection.getMetaData().getURL();
    connection.close();
}
```

For MySql, the return URL will be in form of:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/edm?useUnicode=true
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sessionFactory.getDialect();
```

gives you the `Dialect` and

```
sessionFactory.getSettings().getConnectionProvider().getConnection().getMetaData().getURL();
```

provides you the connection url.

**Note**: This only works with the `SessionFactoryImpl` class, not with the interface

Answer (score 3):

Or you can try:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactoryImpl = (SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactory;
Properties props = sessionFactoryImpl.getProperties();
String url = props.get("hibernate.connection.url").toString();
String[] urlArray = url.split(":");
String db_name = urlArray[urlArray.length - 1];
```

Comment: I was hoping this would be a way I could look at all Hibernate properties, but it  seems that it only works if the config is being read from the file hibernate.cfg.xml. I am using Spring to configure Hibernate so it doesn't work. Any idea how to access the SessionFactoryImpl that is created by Spring?

Comment: I figured out that I could get the SessionFactory from Spring like this `(SessionFactoryImpl) appContext.getBean("sessionFactory");` where appContext is my ApplicationContext. Using this I can get lots of properties, but oddly not the *hibernate.connection.url* mentioned in this post.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is to get the currently configured properties and then get your db URL using key "hibernate.connection.url". The following code prints current session url

```
System.out.println(sessionFactory.getProperties().get("hibernate.connection.url"))
```

on my system I get

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:15432/tempdb
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have either a hibernate.properties or a hibernate.cfg.xml, you can allways read any information off these files.

Answer (score 1):

and you can try this code:

```
String url = null;
try {
    url = getSession().connection().getMetaData().getURL().toString();
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String[] urlArray = url.split(":");
String db_name = urlArray[1];
```

;)

Answer (score 1):

For Hibernate 5.2.0, to get the datasource..

```
SessionFactoryImplementor entityManagerFactory = (SessionFactoryImplementor) sessionFactory.openSession().getEntityManagerFactory();
DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl connectionProvider = (DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl) entityManagerFactory.getServiceRegistry().getService(ConnectionProvider.class);
BasicDataSource dataSource = (BasicDataSource) connectionProvider.getDataSource();
dataSource.getUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect it in variable view in IntelliJ as below

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource)entityManagerFactory.getProperties()
.get("hibernate.connection.datasource");

Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
String databaseName = connection.getCatalog();
```

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With Hibernate5 and C3P0 managed connection pool, the following returned me the JDBC URL:

```
    ((DriverManagerDataSource) 
            ((WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource) 
            ((ComboPooledDataSource) hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getProperties()
                    .get("hibernate.connection.datasource"))
            .getConnectionPoolDataSource())
            .getNestedDataSource()).getJdbcUrl();
```