# Get the url that the Connection uses to connect the database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to get the url that the Connection uses to connect the database as following :

```
getEntityManager().unwrap(SessionImplementor.class).connection().getMetaData().getURL();
```

But I get this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available
```

How can I solve this ?

## Edit:

I don't understand why this question was considered as duplicated to a Hibernate solution, I'm using JPA, so I'm trying to get the url using `entityManager` and not `sessionFactory`.

Comment: Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351443/how-to-know-underlying-database-name-from-hibernate-provider

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know underlying database name from hibernate provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351443/how-to-know-underlying-database-name-from-hibernate-provider)

Comment: @R.Daumann how is that duplicated ? as you can see I'm using `entityManager` and not `sessionFactory` so I'm trying to get the url using JPA and not Hibernate, that's why I used `unwrap` to allow access to the provider-specific API !!!

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add the `@Transactional` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The [SessionImplementor Interface](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionImplementor.html) is form Hibernate, so which JPA Implementation are you using then?

Comment: I'm using Hibernate, but I don't have the access to the sessionFactory, unless I do `getEntityManager().unwrap(SessionImplementor.class)` which throws the error: `No transactional EntityManager available`

Comment: Could you try to get the connection like this:
`em.getTransaction().begin();
java.sql.Connection conn = em.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
// ...
em.getTransaction().commit();`